# AMP-EMAIL: Iterate list of items from amp-state

Tags: amp-html, amp-email

I'm trying to find a way to iterate over data that's stored in `amp-state` in an `amp-email` setting. This issue stems from the fact that I want my server to return different data to the user based on their input (zipcode in this case). Since I can't use `amp-bind`'s functionality on the `src` of `amp-list` in an `amp-email`, I'm not sure how one would accomplish this.

Contrived example of my code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ⚡4email>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <amp-state id="state">
      <script type="application/json">
        {}
      </script>
    </amp-state>

    <div class="container">
      <!-- STEP 1 -->
      <div class="step" id="step1" [hidden]="page != 'home'">
        <form
          id="form1"
          method="POST"
          action-xhr="https://localhost:3333/getDataFromZip"
          on="submit-success:
              AMP.setState({
                  page: 'step2',
                  returnedData: event.response.data,
              })"
        >
          <input type="text" name="zip" />
          <button type="submit">
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <!-- STEP 2 -->
      <div class="step" id="step2" [hidden]="page != 'step2'">
        <!-- ITERATE OVER state.returnedData HERE -->

      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to iterate an AMP state in that way.

You have two options:

## Option 1

Use mustache templates instead. You can do this inside an `amp-form` by putting a mustache template inside an element that has the `submit-success` attribute (see the [Success/error response rendering](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-form/#success/error-response-rendering) section of `amp-form` docs for more information):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ⚡4email>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>

  <body>
    <amp-state id="state">
      <script type="application/json">
        {}
      </script>
    </amp-state>

    <div class="container">
      <!-- STEP 1 -->
      <div class="step" id="step1">
        <form
          id="form1"
          method="POST"
          action-xhr="https://localhost:3333/getDataFromZip"
          on="submit-success:
              AMP.setState({
                  page: 'step2'
              })"
        >
          <div [hidden]="page != 'home'">
            <input type="text" name="zip" />
            <button type="submit">
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>

          <!-- STEP 2 -->
          <div submit-success >
            <template type="amp-mustache">
              <div class="step" id="step2" [hidden]="page != 'step2'">
                {{#data}}
                <!-- add template for each item here -->
                {{/data}}
              </div>
            </template>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

## Option 2

If you have a very small number of items in an array in your `amp-state`, you can hardcode array accesses. For example, if you'd like a `<p>` tag for every array item:

```
<amp-state id="state">
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      items: ['a', 'b', 'c']
    }
  </script>
</amp-state>

<p [hidden]="!state.items[0]" [text]="state.items[0]"></p>
<p [hidden]="!state.items[1]" [text]="state.items[1]"></p>
<p [hidden]="!state.items[2]" [text]="state.items[2]"></p>
<p [hidden]="!state.items[3]" [text]="state.items[3]"></p>
<p [hidden]="!state.items[4]" [text]="state.items[4]"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for this response. I did end up going with Option 1 prior to seeing this in the end and while it wasn't idea, I'm working my way around the constraints imposed by lack of access to the AMP State in emails.